# How to handle `&` symbol in search query

Tags: javascript, query-string

Given URL `http://localhost:3000/?team=Video%20QA%20&%20Test%20Team&teamCode=XXXXX` while decoded used *URLSearchParams* is represented as `{"team":"Video QA "," Test Team":"","teamCode":"XXXXX"}` which is wrong.
How to handle & symbol in query string to get from exampled URL this look:
`{"team":"Video QA & Test Team","teamCode":"XXXXX"}`

`const searchParams = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).entries());`

or tryed query-string lib, same. & symbol recognized as new object key
`qs.parse('http://localhost:3000/?team=Video%20QA%20&%20Test%20Team&teamCode=XXXXX')`

---

`encodeURI` won't encode `&` symbol correctly. To avoid this issue, I have used `encodeURIComponent` and the problem get resolved.

Comment: That `&` should have been URL encoded to `%26`. As it stands, there is no distinction between it and an actual `&` query string character.

Comment: Browsers have a nice Class called URLSearchParams that will handle all this for you -> `new URLSearchParams({"team":"Video QA & Test Team","teamCode":"XXXXX"}).toString()`   result -> `team=Video+QA+%26+Test+Team&teamCode=XXXXX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` should be encoded as `%26`

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent('Video QA & Test Team'))
```

```
Video%20QA%20%26%20Test%20Team
```

Comment: How do I force the browser to use `%26` in this case? If you try paste just `?team=Video QA & Test Team&teamCode=ATA5BH` it will automatically convert to one as in the question.

Comment: I doubt you can do that by pasting the test into the url. Browsers will interpret `&` as a separator in the first place

Comment: @CityNIGHT — That's rather like asking "Bob wants to search for *dogs* but pastes *cats*, how can I convert that automatically?". Reliably correcting errors in external data is hard and most of the time shouldn't be necessary. Whomever is pasting a malformed URL should stop doing that.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, this really helps in understanding how it works and where the problem is. Basically I have used ``encodeURI`` instead of ``encodeURIComponent`` and that is why faced the issue with wrong ``&`` symbol encoding.